# How to resolve browser specific (Firefox) "No .NET call dispatcher has been set" within blazor (WASM)

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am having difficulties with slow loading of my page. I find that in the debug console on Firefox, there is an error `No .NET call dispatcher has been set.`, However in Chrome I do not see this error.

I assume this has to do with my use of Java script interlop in my C# service.

Something that bugs me the most is that the page will load and the java script file does work. The grids and so on resize accordingly. This maybe suggests I am adding in my service incorrectly or referencing the java script file at the wrong place, but I am not sure.

My resize service is registered as scoped, and I inject it into razor pages that need it. Every page has a subscriber and dispose method called when that razor page/component is created or destroyed.

The C# browser resize service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using StudyMate.Models.Models;

namespace StudyMate.Client.Services
{
    public class BrowserResizeService
    {
        private readonly IJSRuntime _JSRuntime;

        public event Action OnResize;

        private static BrowserResizeService _instance = null;
        public BrowserResizeService(IJSRuntime js)
        {
            _JSRuntime = js;
            _instance = this;
        }

        [JSInvokable]
        public static void OnBrowserResize()
        {
            _instance?.OnResize?.Invoke();
        }

        public async Task<BrowserDimension> GetDimensions()
        {
            try
            {
                return await _JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<BrowserDimension>("getDimensions");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return new BrowserDimension { Height = 800, Width = 1000 };
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Example of use within razor page:

```
@page "/ManageChosenSubjects"

@inject StudentService studentService
@inject SubjectService subjectService
@inject UserService userService
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject BrowserResizeService ResizeService

...

@code
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }

...

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            ResizeService.OnResize += OnResize;
        }
    }

    private async Task OnResize()
    {
        await GetDimensions();
    }

    async Task GetDimensions()
    {
        var dimension = await ResizeService.GetDimensions();
        Height = dimension.Height - 220;
        Width = dimension.Width - 400;
        Console.WriteLine($"H: {Height}, W: {Width}");
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ResizeService.OnResize -= OnResize;
    }
}
```

My index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>StudyMate</title>
    <base href="/" />
    ...
    <script src="/JavaScript/browser-resize.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error- WHY щ（ﾟДﾟщ）
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="/Libs/InputFile/inputfile.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The java script file:

```
window.getDimensions = function () {
    return {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    };
};

var browserResize = {

    getInnerHeight: function () {

        return window.innerHeight;

    },

    getInnerWidth: function () {

        return window.innerWidth;

    },

    resized: function () {

        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync("StudyMate.Client", 'OnBrowserResize');

    }

};

window.addEventListener("resize", browserResize.resized);
```

Comment: Could you please add `StudyMate.Client.Services.BrowserResizeService` code?

Comment: I have added the C# script. I have found a fix for the object reference not set to instance of object and so I have editted my issue's description accordingly.